# RecyclerView showing database entries as null strings

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, retrofit, adapter

I'm working on an Android app which uses PHP API and retrofit. My SQL database has an "orders" table which is the result of join between "users" and "foods" tables. My code works successfully in showing "users" and "foods" in recyclerviews in different fragments, but the same method fails to show the "orders" and I get an empty recyclerview (with the right numbers of rows and items of the orders table) but the strings are null and the integers are 0. The code runs with no error. I also tested PHP request in POSTMAN and the response is correct, so the PHP code is working well. Could you please tell me what is wrong with this code? Could the problem be related to using columns of other tables in the join query or something else? Please help me friends.

I found this in Logcat: 2019-08-08 00:43:52.967 21951-21951/com.nikappzaar.app.foodtakeout E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

```php
public function getAllOrders(){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare(
                                "SELECT o.oid, o.uid, o.fid, o.quantity, o.otime
                                   , f.fname, f.unitprice
                                   , u.phone, u.uname, u.uaddress
                                 FROM orders o
                                 INNER JOIN foods f
                                   on o.fid = f.fid
                                 INNER JOIN users u
                                   on o.uid = u.uid ;");
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $stmt->bind_result($oid, $uid, $fid, $quantity, $otime, $fname, $unitprice, $phone, $uname, $uaddress);
            $orders = array(); 
            while($stmt->fetch()){ 
                $order = array(); 
                $order['o.oid'] = $oid; 
                $order['o.uid'] = $uid; 
                $order['o.fid'] = $fid; 
                $order['o.quantity']=$quantity; 
                $order['o.otime'] = $otime;
                $order['f.fname'] = $fname; 
                $order['f.unitprice'] = $unitprice; 
                $order['u.phone']=$phone; 
                $order['u.uname'] = $uname; 
                $order['u.uaddress'] = $uaddress;
                array_push($orders, $order);
            }             
            return $orders; 
        }
```

OperatorHomeFargment.java

```java
public class OperatorHomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private OrdersAdapter adapter;
    private List<Order> orderList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        Call<OrdersResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getOrders();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<OrdersResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OrdersResponse> call, Response<OrdersResponse> response) {

                orderList = response.body().getOrders();
                adapter = new OrdersAdapter(getActivity(), orderList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OrdersResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

OrdersAdapter.java

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.OrdersViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Order> orderList;

    public OrdersAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Order> orderList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrdersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_orders, parent, false);
        return new OrdersViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrdersViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Order order = orderList.get(position);

        holder.textViewOId.setText(String.format("%d", order.getOId()));
        holder.textViewOTime.setText(order.getOTime());
        holder.textViewFName.setText(order.getFName());
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText(String.format("%d", order.getQuantity()));
        holder.textViewUnitPrice.setText(String.format("%d", order.getUnitPrice()));
        holder.textViewPhone.setText(order.getPhone());
        holder.textViewUName.setText(order.getUName());
        holder.textViewUAddress.setText(order.getUAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderList.size();
    }

    class OrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewOId, textViewOTime, textViewFName, textViewQuantity, textViewUnitPrice,
                 textViewPhone, textViewUName, textViewUAddress;

        public OrdersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewOId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOId);
            textViewOTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOTime);
            textViewFName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFName);
            textViewQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
            textViewUnitPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUnitPrice);
            textViewPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
            textViewUName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFName);
            textViewUAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUAddress);

        }
    }
}
```

Order.java

```
public class Order {

    private int oid, uid, fid, quantity, unitprice;
    private String otime, fname, phone, uname, uaddress;

    public Order(int oid, int uid, int fid, int quantity, String otime,
                 String fname, int unitprice, String phone, String uname, String uaddress) {
        this.oid = oid;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.fid = fid;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.otime = otime;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.unitprice = unitprice;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.uname = uname;
        this.uaddress = uaddress;
    }

    public int getOId() {
        return oid;
    }

    public int getUId() {
        return uid;
    }

    public int getFId() {
        return fid;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getOTime() {
        return otime;
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return fname;
    }

    public int getUnitPrice() {
        return unitprice;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getUName() {
        return uname;
    }

    public String getUAddress() {
        return uaddress;
    }

}
```

recyclerview_orders.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewQuantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUnitPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPhone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_orders.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure your app gets orders successfuly? Can you log count of the orders after this line `orderList = response.body().getOrders();`?

Comment: I already have problem with adding orders from app, but as I entered orders manually in my database I expected to see them in the recyclerview, as I get the orders in my browser or POSTMAN response. Am I wrong?
How can I "log" the count in my code? sorry I'm not a professional android developer and I'm just learning. Could you please help me. Thank you

Comment: @faranjit I used this line of code Log.w("MyApp", String.valueOf(orderList.size())); and I get the correct number of orders so the app gets orders successfully.

Comment: Just add Log.d("tag name",  order list.size()) after that line

Comment: And watch in logcat what prints out.

Comment: Dear @faranjit I did so and got the size of the list successfully. So the app gets orders but displays strings as null and integers as 0. I don't know why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from comments that you have a problem with parsing response json to model class. Can you try to put a default constructor in `Order` class and `@SerializedName("json_key_name")` annotation to top of the attributes which has different name from json keys.

Comment: Dear @faranjit thank you so much. That's it. I did so and it's just working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if you call  `OperatorHomeFragment` inside of `Fragment` using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead `getSupportFragmentManager()` in `FragmentManager`

Comment: I'm already using getSupportFargmentManager() to call OperatorHomeFragment. The same code works well for simple tables like "users" and "foods", but not working for joint query "orders" !